# Problem running livecd on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, live-cd

I'm trying to run a livecd on virtaulbox (Host OS = Win10, tried ubuntu & gparted live CDs).

I've attached the iso

[image]

Reboot and hit F12

[image]

And got this:

> FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.

[image]

What should I try next?

Comment: Can you boot an Ubuntu live system?

Comment: @Takkat I tried now, and no I can't.

Comment: You should then [edit] you question with that to make it on topic (gparted live ISO would not be on topic here).

Comment: @Takkat done, tnx.

Comment: Please try verify the hash of the ".iso" files using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM and http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/ to verify that they are correct.

Comment: @ShlomiFish - The ubuntu live CD iso is good, I recently downloaded it and used it to install the machine in the first place.

Comment: @ShlomiFish - I verified the sha256 of the file, it is not faulty.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved!

The problem was that I was trying to hook the iso to my SATA controller, instead to my IDE controller.

So:

1. Remove the first blank IDE controller
2. Add gparted iso to the IDE controller.
3. Make sure it's set to Primary Master (not sure if mandatory, this worked for me).